# CANCEL in UISearchBar taking a real long time

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

Hitting the cancel button on the UISeachBar in a UITableView loops forever, and continues to consume memory. Here are my conditions & findings.

1) Using a custom view for the backgroundview of the table
2) A long list of items retrieved from core-data
3) Start the search, type a few letter -- all ok. I get the results that I need
4) Hit cancel - and the waiting starts

I used the CPU profiler to debug and found that it got stuck in a call to [layoutsbelowifneeded].

I removed the custom view with the background image, and everything works great.

Any reasons for this to happen?

UPDATE:

Here is the code that I am using:

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableview_background.png"];
UIImageView *view=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
wltvc.tableView.backgroundView=view;
```

Comment: How exactly are you adding the background image for your table view?

Comment: `UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableview_background.png"];`
`UIImageView *view=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];`
`wltvc.tableView.backgroundView=view;`@sangony

Comment: What method do you call that code in?

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a custom view to just add the background to the tableview. That can be done on the default uitableviewcontroller like -

`UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableview_background.png"]; 
UIImageView *view=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[view setFrame:self.tableView.frame]; 
self.tableView.backgroundView = view;`

Comment: UISearchViewController can have the same code as well